# Error with pio import

Tags: predictionio

I can create application normally, but cannot import data. Neither for pio train and pio deploy.
Can anyone help me with that?

```
[INFO] [App$] Initialized Event Store for this app ID: 1.
[INFO] [App$] Created new app:
[INFO] [App$]       Name: 1
[INFO] [App$]         ID: 1
[INFO] [App$] Access Key:     v9gaJRl8AD4iL1mEvaZuJ8swaLiAEqVUzWdXlVkkCnbKKBMFSBljIq5dZ02JaAkL
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.30/recommend_361
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:75)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1148)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
at scalikejdbc.CommonsConnectionPool.borrow(CommonsConnectionPool.scala:43)
at scalikejdbc.DB$.autoCommit(DB.scala:214)
at io.prediction.data.storage.jdbc.JDBCChannels.<init>(JDBCChannels.scala:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at io.prediction.data.storage.Storage$.getDataObject(Storage.scala:303)
at io.prediction.data.storage.Storage$.getDataObjectFromRepo(Storage.scala:263)
at io.prediction.data.storage.Storage$.getMetaDataChannels(Storage.scala:376)
at io.prediction.tools.imprt.FileToEvents$$anonfun$main$1.apply(FileToEvents.scala:65)
at io.prediction.tools.imprt.FileToEvents$$anonfun$main$1.apply(FileToEvents.scala:63)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at io.prediction.tools.imprt.FileToEvents$.main(FileToEvents.scala:63)
at io.prediction.tools.imprt.FileToEvents.main(FileToEvents.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the driver jar file available to the driver so run

```
pio import --appid <appId> --input </path/to/json_file> -- --driver-class-path </path/to/mysql-connector-java.jar>
```

Comment: Dear Pat, thank you for your reply. I can import now.