# PredictionIO: Installing JDBC driver for postgresql on OSX

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, predictionio

I'm trying to follow the PredictionIO tutorial for a text classification enginge [provided here.](https://docs.prediction.io/demo/textclassification/) I'm using OSX and PredictionIO together with PostgreSQL.

When trying to import data into my naked App with the command

```
pio import --appid 1 --input data/stopwords.json
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/pio
```

So obviously the JDBC driver is missing or not linked appropriately. Here's where my trouble begins. Naively I downloaded the postgres jdbc driver [from this source](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html). I read that I need to add it to java's "CLASSPATH", so I tried this by adding

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:~/java-extensions/postgresql-9.4.1207.jre6.jar
```

to my bash configuration. Unfortunatly this does not work. A similar error situation is discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/predictionio-user/jdbc$3Apostgresql$3A$2F$2Flocalhost$2Fpio/predictionio-user/yJexMh5HpHc/whVkR9qUAgAJ) - but with my knowledge I'm not able to extract useful hints from it.

--

*Version details:*

psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.5 installed via homebrew

OSX Yosemite

PredictionIO 0.9.5

`pio status` reports "Your system is all ready to go."

Comment: Have you run `install.sh`, because it looks like that downloads the driver. Note that setting the `CLASSPATH` environment variable usually doesn't work well as a lot of Java applications don't actually use it (not sure if that applies to predictionio)

Comment: Yes, I ran predictionio's `install.sh` initially and its output told me that I have to install PostgreSQL manually (but it was already installed on my machine before, so I only created an approrpriate role and db for PredictionIO).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with pio import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691711/error-with-pio-import)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As alex9311 pointed out, the `pio import` nowadays accepts a flag to specify the driver location:

```
pio import --appid 1 --input data/stopwords.json --driver-class-path WHEREVER/postgresql-9.4-1204-jdbc41.jar
```

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691711/error-with-pio-import)

Answer (score 3):

See this Google Group thread: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/predictionio-user/yJexMh5HpHc/discussion

tl;dr :

Fixed in next release of PredictionIO (v0.9.6),  coming soon.

Workaround for earlier PIO versions :

```
pio train -- --driver-class-path WHEREVER/postgresql-9.4-1204-jdbc41.jar
```

Comment: As stated initially I already know the Google Group, but this solution does not work with the `pio import` command, since it has no `--driver-class-path` flag to set. Do you know if the issue is fixed for the `pio import` command in the next release, too?

Comment: I managed to get the --driver-class-path flag working with import, I'll add it to the answer